# How to make Siri audible to other person on the phone?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

When Siri reads something I can hear it well.

But a person on the other end of a phone call hears nothing of it. That's a good default.

But how can I make the other person on the phone hear what Siri reads for me (not always but only when I want it)?

Hardware: iPhone 6

Background information about my motive:
In Germany we do not have a method to send a GPS position in a standardized way to the national emergency call center. We have no way at all to send a text message to that center. So my idea was, to let Siri read that coordinates. I want to have that for my old father, who walks often alone in the woods. No, he does not want a wearable. I have to deal with an iphone.

iOS: 12.4.1

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It is something like you are trying to play Youtube video on your phone and want to listen by the caller who is hearing you. Would you be very much interested to know if it is possible? 
You will be using your Microphone to communicate during a call and your phone no longer act as Speaker.

Comment: I'm looking for a way that for that time, while Siri speaks, the microphone should be deactivated or the device should act like an audio device with two inputs. One of the mic and another by Siri.